# Alternative c:if in JSF

Tags: jsf, jstl, oracle-adf

Does someone know a alternative to `<c:if>` for view render time, or even if that is possible. For what I have search until now it doesn't exist, or the alternative would be using the `rendered` attribute, but for me doesn't really work.

```
<af:listView value="#{bindings.date.collectionModel}" var="item" id="lv1">
    <af:listItem id="li2">
        <af:iterator id="i1" value="#{bindings.list.collectionModel}" var="row">
            <c:if test="#{item.bindings.attrid.inputValue eq row.attrid}">
                <ui:param name="varUI" value="true" />
                <c:set var="varC" value="true" />
            </c:if>
        </af:iterator>
        <af:outputText value="#{varUI}" id="otqaswq"/>
        <!--<af:outputText value="#{varC}" id="otqawq"/>-->
        <af:selectBooleanCheckbox text="Activated" id="sbc2" value="#{varUI}"/>
    </af:listItem>
</af:listView>
```

So in the code above I know that `c:` they run in different time, view build time and not on the render time.
What I needed was that the `af:selectBooleanCheckbox` would appear true or false depending if there are values with the same value.
My question is, someone know a alternative way of doing this?

Comment: So you want that if to execute and change after the browser has rendered it? That's something you'd need to do with javascript I'd think.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - What are you really wanting to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

rendered should 100% work, your expression may be incorrect.
Switching to another alternative where you will use exactly the same expression will lead you in the very same place.

Comment: This won't work either, because `<ui:param>` and `<c:set>` are evaluated *before* any `rendered` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an `<af:iterator>` to conditionally set a value using `<ui:param>` or `<c:set>`, because they are both tag handlers which are evaluated *before* `<af:iterator>`. You might use `<c:forEach>` instead, but that requires some collection to iterate over. A `javax.faces.model.DataModel` like `#{bindings.list.collectionModel}` will most likely not work.

But to be honest, you should implement some Java method which will give you the desired value (`true` or `false`) instead of trying to implement this logic in terms of JSF tags.